# Cannot access K8s dashboard after installation of kubeadm-dind-cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, docker-in-docker

I am using [kubeadm-dind-cluster](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubeadm-dind-cluster) a Kubernetes multi-node cluster for developer of Kubernetes and projects that extend Kubernetes. Based on kubeadm and DIND (Docker in Docker).

I have a fresh Centos 7 install on which I have just run `./dind-cluster-v1.13.sh up`. I did not set any other values and am using all the default values for networking.

All appears well:

```
[root@node01 dind-cluster]# kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kube-master   Ready    master   23h   v1.13.0
kube-node-1   Ready    <none>   23h   v1.13.0
kube-node-2   Ready    <none>   23h   v1.13.0

[root@node01 dind-cluster]# kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: http://127.0.0.1:32769
  name: dind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: dind
    user: ""
  name: dind
current-context: dind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
[root@node01 dind-cluster]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://127.0.0.1:32769
KubeDNS is running at http://127.0.0.1:32769/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
[root@node01 dind-cluster]#
```

and it appears healthy:

```
[root@node01 dind-cluster]# curl -w  '\n' http://127.0.0.1:32769/healthz
ok
```

I know the dashboard service is there:

```
[root@node01 dind-cluster]# kubectl get services kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort   10.102.82.8   <none>        80:31990/TCP   23h
```

however any attempt to access it is refused:

```
[root@node01 dind-cluster]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:8080; Connection refused

[root@node01 dind-cluster]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ui
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:8080; Connection refused
```

I also see the following in the firewall log:

```
2019-02-05 19:45:19 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C DOCKER -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 32769 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.192.0.2:8080 ! -i br-669b654fc9cd' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

2019-02-05 19:45:19 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t filter -C DOCKER ! -i br-669b654fc9cd -o br-669b654fc9cd -p tcp -d 10.192.0.2 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).

2019-02-05 19:45:19 WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w2 -t nat -C POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 10.192.0.2 -d 10.192.0.2 --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Any suggestions on how I actually access the dashboard externally from my development machine? I don't want to use the proxy to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access `kubernetes-dashboard` using the following addresses:

ClusterIP(works for other pods in cluster):

```
http://10.102.82.8:80/
```

NodePort(works for every host who can access cluster nodes using their IPs):

```
http://clusterNodeIP:31990/
```

Usually Kubernetes dashboard uses `https` protocol, so you may need to use different ports in request to `kubernetes-dashboard` Service for that.

You can also access the dashboard using `kube-apiserver` as a proxy:

Directly to dashboard Pod:

```
https://<master-ip>:<apiserver-port>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/https:kubernetes-dashboard-pod-name:/proxy/#!/login
```

To dashboard ClusterIP service:

```
https://<master-ip>:<apiserver-port>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/login
```

I can guess that `<master-ip>:<apiserver-port>` would mean `127.0.0.1:32769` in your case.

Comment: I ultimately want to access it from another host, so let me see if I can get routing to work to 10.102.82.8 and through the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, you'd indeed expect that *everything works out-of-the box.* However, seemingly the setup is missing a suitable service-account to access and manage the cluster through the dashboard.

Note I might be entirely mislead here, and maybe [kubeadm-dind-cluster](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubeadm-dind-cluster) in fact provides such an account. Please note also that this project has been discontinued some time ago.

Anyway, here is how I fixed that problem. Hopefully it's of some help for other people (still) trying that out...

- define the missing account and Role binding: Create a yaml file

  ```
  # ------------------- Dashboard Secret ------------------- #
  # ...already available
  # ------------------- Dashboard Service Account ------------------- #
  # ...already available
  # ------------------- Dashboard Cluster Admin Account ------------------- #
  #
  # added by Ichthyo 2019-2
  #  - ServiceAccount and ClusterRoleBinding
  #  - allows administrative Access intoto Namespace kube-system
  #  - necessary to log-in via Kubernetes-Dashboard
  #
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    name: dash-admin
    namespace: kube-system
  ---
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: ClusterRoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: dash-admin
  roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: cluster-admin
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: dash-admin
    namespace: kube-system

  ---
  # ------------------- Dashboard Role & Role Binding ------------------- #

  kind: Role
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
    namespace: kube-system
  rules:
    # Allow Dashboard to create 'kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder' secret.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    verbs: ["create"]
    # Allow Dashboard to create 'kubernetes-dashboard-settings' config map.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    verbs: ["create"]
    # Allow Dashboard to get, update and delete Dashboard exclusive secrets.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder", "kubernetes-dashboard-certs"]
    verbs: ["get", "update", "delete"]
    # Allow Dashboard to get and update 'kubernetes-dashboard-settings' config map.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    resourceNames: ["kubernetes-dashboard-settings"]
    verbs: ["get", "update"]
    # Allow Dashboard to get metrics from heapster.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services"]
    resourceNames: ["heapster"]
    verbs: ["proxy"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services/proxy"]
    resourceNames: ["heapster", "http:heapster:", "https:heapster:"]
    verbs: ["get"]

  ---
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: RoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
    namespace: kube-system
  roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: Role
    name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
    namespace: kube-system
  ```
- Apply it to the already running cluster

  ```
  kubectl apply -f k8s-dashboard-RBAC.yaml
  ```
- Then find out the security token corresponding to `dash-admin`

  ```
  kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep dash-admin | awk '{print $1}')|egrep '^token:\s+'|awk '{print $2}
  ```
- finally paste the extracted Token into the login screen